# How to make checkbox checked from the query parameters?

Tags: angular, checkbox, checked, query-string, angular-activatedroute

I want to bind my checkboxes to query parameters.
For example: I have:

```
http://localhost:4200/products?pageNumber=1&pageSize=16&lenscolor=1&lenscolor=2
```

And after page loading, my colors checkboxes with appropriate id (1 and 2) must be checked. I guess, that the best way is via [checked], but don't know how it implement correctly.

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let lensColor of lensColors; let i = index">
        <input id="lensColor{{lensColor.id}}" type="checkbox" name="lensColor" (change)="doLensColorsFilter($event, lensColor.id)">
        <label>{{lensColor.uaName}}</label>
      </div>
```

.ts

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  lensColors: Color[];
  searchedLensColors = new Array<number>();

constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private productsService: ProductsService) {
    this.routeSubscription = route.params.subscribe(params => this.category = params.category);
    this.querySubscription = route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (queryParam: any) => {
        this.searchedLensColors = queryParam.lenscolor;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadLensColors();

}

private loadLensColors() {
    this.productsService.getLensColors().subscribe((data: Color[]) => {
      this.lensColors = data;
    });
  }

private doLensColorsFilter(event, lensColorId) {
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;
    if (isChecked) {
      this.searchedLensColors.push(lensColorId);
    } else {
      const index = this.searchedLensColors.findIndex(el => el === lensColorId);
      this.searchedLensColors.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/products'], {queryParams: {lenscolor: this.searchedLensColors}, queryParamsHandling: 'merge'});

  }

}
```

my lensColors:

```
[
 {id: 1, name: "black", uaName: "Чорний"}
 {id: 2, name: "white", uaName: "Білий"}
 {id: 3, name: "yellow", uaName: "Жовтий"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

My english is very poor, but there are several ways.

the first

```
 <input id="lensColor{{lensColor.id}}" [checked]="lensColor.checked" type="checkbox" name="lensColor" (change)="doLensColorsFilter($event, lensColor.id)">
```

the second

```
  <input id="lensColor{{lensColor.id}}" [(ngModel)]="lensColor.checked" type="checkbox" name="lensColor" (change)="doLensColorsFilter($event, lensColor.id)">
```

in booth case, you must create this field in array, if contains info check true.

I hope to be helpfull.